# Asp.net Core Razor Pages Complex Databinding Select List to Entity List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, databinding, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor pages. I would like to bind a `<select>` list to an object's property that is a list of another object (Report.EventyTypes). Consider the following code:

**Report.cs**

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public List<EventType> EventTypes { get; set; } = new List<EventType>();
}

public class EventType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = "";
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;

    public EventType() { }

    public EventType(int id, string text, bool active)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Text = text;
        this.Active = active;
    }
}
```

**TestReport.chtml**

```
@page
@model TestRazor2022.Pages.TestReportModel
@{
}
<form method="post">
    <div ID="pnlHeaderTitle">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="TheReport.Id" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <label asp-for="TheReport.EventTypes" />
            <select asp-items="Model.EventTypesOptions" asp-for="EventTypes">
            </select>
        </div><br />
        <div>
            <label asp-for="TheReport.PersonName">Person Involved:&nbsp;</label>
            <input asp-for="TheReport.PersonName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TestReport.chtml.cs**

```
public class TestReportModel : PageModel
{                
    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectListItem> EventTypesOptions { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public IEnumerable<string> EventTypes { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public Report TheReport { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        EventTypesOptions = GetEventTypes().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Text }).ToList();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        foreach (string et in EventTypes)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(et);
            TheReport.EventTypes.Add(GetEventType(id));
        }
        //call to save TheReport to datastore
    }

    public List<EventType> GetEventTypes()
    {
        List<EventType> eventTypes = new List<EventType>();
        eventTypes.Add(new EventType(1, "Injury", true));
        eventTypes.Add(new EventType(2, "Illness", true));
        eventTypes.Add(new EventType(3, "Near Miss", true));
        eventTypes.Add(new EventType(4, "Property Damage", true));
        return eventTypes;
    }

    public EventType GetEventType(int id)
    {
        return GetEventTypes().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

If I understand it correctly, in the PageModel, I need to have a `[BindProperty]` enabled property `(EventTypeOptions)` that I use to generate the `<select>` options and then when the form is posted, the selected items in the list should be bound to a DIFFERENT `[BindProperty]` enabled property `(EventTypes)`. From there I have to use the EventTypes property to iterate through and add items to my `TheReport.EventTypes` property.

My question is, is there a better way to bind the items from my `<select>` list back to my `TheReport.EventTypes` property? (and in the case of an edit page, from my `TheReport.EventTypes` to the `<select>` list)?